# Unicode→CP932変換時にU+301Cを0x8160に変換するには？

Tags: emacs

"GNU Emacs 24.4.1 (i686-pc-cygwin) of 2015-02-01 on gnupack"を使っています。
UTF-8などUnicode系の文字コードからCP932に変換する時に、波ダッシュ(U+301C)が変換できません。

CP932の波ダッシュ(0x8160)がUnicodeの全角チルダ(U+FF5E)に変換されるのは、Windowsを使っている限り受け入れるしかないとしても、Unicodeの波ダッシュ(U+301C)がCP932の波ダッシュ(0x8160)に変換されないのは不便だと思いました。

Unicodeの波ダッシュ(U+301C)をCP932の波ダッシュ(0x8160)に変換するように設定するには、どうすれば良いでしょうか？

＃ググるとcoding-system-putで:decode-translation-tableを書き換えればできそうと思ったのですが、Emacs内部での文字コードの扱い方もEmacs Lispもわからないので…

Comment: `(coding-system-put 'cp932 :encode-translation-table (get 'japanese-ucs-jis-to-cp932-map 'translation-table))` としてみて下さい。

Comment: できました！
japanese-ucs-jis-to-cp932-mapはlanguage/japanese.elで定義されているマップだと思いますが、教えていただいたコードはUnicode→CP932変換前に一旦このマップに従ってUnicode→Unicode変換する処理になるのでしょうか？

Comment: はい、その通りです。それから、ご自身で問題を解決された場合には、ご自身で回答していただけると助かります(1件も回答がないと未解決な質問として扱われてしまいますので)。ご協力お願いします。

Answer (score 2):

以下、heliac2001さんの回答＋自分の補足をまとめました。

```
;; Unicode（内部コード）→CP932変換時に波ダッシュ(U+301C)を波ダッシュ(0x8160)に変換するよう設定する。
;; 波ダッシュと同様の変換問題のある文字も変わる。
;; 対象文字は、"lisp/language/japanese.el"で定義されている
;; japanese-ucs-jis-to-cp932-mapを参照。
(coding-system-put 'cp932 :encode-translation-table
                   (get 'japanese-ucs-jis-to-cp932-map 'translation-table))
```